# Chain validation failed

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I'm having the below `Okhttp` code:

```kotlin
val client = OkHttpClient()

val mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
val body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "tenant_id=xxxx&client_id=xxxx&client_secret=xxxx&resource=xxxx&grant_type=client_credentials")
val request = Request.Builder()
  .url("https://sxxx.com/axxx/oauth2/token")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .build()

val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
```

And want to convert it usint `ktor`, so I wrote the below:

```kotlin
class Greeting {
        private val httpClient = HttpClient {
        }

        @Throws(Exception::class)
        suspend fun greeting(): String {
        val response = httpClient.request {
            method = HttpMethod.Post
            url {
                protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
                host = "sxxx.com"
                path("axxx/oauth2/token")
             //   encodedParameters
                trailingQuery = true
                parameters.append("tenant_id", "xxxx")
                parameters.append("client_id", "xxxx")
                parameters.append("client_secret", "xxxx")
                parameters.append("resource", "xxxx")
                parameters.append("grant_type", "client_credentials")
            }
            headers {
                append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            }
        }
        return response.bodyAsText()
     }
}
```

And calling my new code as:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                    var text by remember {
                        mutableStateOf("Loading")
                    }
                    LaunchedEffect(true){
                        scope.launch {
                            text = try {
                                Greeting().greeting()
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                e.localizedMessage ?: "error"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Greeting(text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(text: String) {
    Text(text = text)
}
```

But instead of getting the required token, I'm getting the response: `Chain validation failed`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that:

- Your server certificate is valid.
- Your android system datetime is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the VPN connection, but still getting wrong response, instead of getting the response as JSON including the `token` I'm getting it as 'text/html` which is the login page! what else could be wrong at my code? knowing that I'm getting the response status as `200 OK`

Comment: I suggest you try to read html body of your current response. There will probably be a message to user about what's going on.